# Tracing MPI_Reduce

Tags: mpi, reduce, mpich

So I'm pretty sure this is impossible but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Working with MPICH. I would like to perform some reductions on a derived struct type with a user-defined reduction op. For my purposes I need to know exactly what's happening inside the MPI_Reduce, i.e., the order of the Send/Recv calls and what information is passed where.

Now, according to the code, the MPICH2 implementation of MPI_Reduce always uses a binomial tree algorithm for user-defined ops, so I can always reconstruct what's happening if really pressed, but I was wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no better way to trace the inner working of MPI collective operations. The standard tracing interface in MPI is based around the PMPI paradigm: all `MPI_*` calls are implemented as *weak aliases* of the actual MPI functions. The actual functions are available under the `PMPI_*` name (with the `PMPI_*` calls being either the real implementations or aliases too). This allows tracer libraries to declare their own `MPI_*` functions that call `PMPI_*` while generating trace events before and after the call. For example:

```c
int MPI_Reduce(void *sendbuf, void *recvbuf, int count,
               MPI_Datatype datatype, MPI_Op op, int root, MPI_Comm comm)
{
   int result;

   trace_event_start("MPI_Reduce");
   result = PMPI_Reduce(sendbuf, recvbuf, count, datatype, op, root, comm);
   trace_event_end("MPI_Reduce");

   return result;
}
```

When this code is linked with the rest of the program, all calls to `MPI_Reduce` are replaced with calls to the tracing version (since `MPI_Reduce` was originally a weak alias, the linker won't complain about the symbol being redefined).

Now the real problem in your case is that `MPI_Reduce` is implemented not using calls to `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` but rather using calls to the low-level MPICH2 functions, e.g. `MPIC_Send_ft` and `MPIC_Recv_ft`. These cannot be intercepted using the PMPI mechanism. What you can do in this case is to extract the code from the MPICH2 source and replace the internal calls with calls to `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv`, then trace the resulting implementation.

I have done the procedure described above and it works quite well with Open MPI except for a minor inconvenience - once you provide your own implementation of an MPI function, e.g. `MPI_Reduce`, it is no longer a weak alias and linking with the tracing library could produce a duplicate symbol error. In that case I would simply name my implementation `MyMPI_Reduce` and put `#define MPI_Reduce MyMPI_Reduce` in the beginning of those source files that have to be traced. I'm not that familiar with MPICH2, but from the source code I could tell that it allows user implementations to be plugged in and that would make it easier (e.g. no need to cheat with the preprocessor).

One more thing: MPICH2 has several implementation of the reduction, at least in version 3.0, and it chooses one of them at run time using simple heuristic logic:

```c
if ((count*type_size > MPIR_PARAM_REDUCE_SHORT_MSG_SIZE) &&
    (HANDLE_GET_KIND(op) == HANDLE_KIND_BUILTIN) && (count >= pof2)) {
    /* do a reduce-scatter followed by gather to root. */
    mpi_errno = MPIR_Reduce_redscat_gather(sendbuf, recvbuf, count, datatype, op, root, comm_ptr, errflag);
    if (mpi_errno) {
        /* for communication errors, just record the error but continue */
        *errflag = TRUE;
        MPIU_ERR_SET(mpi_errno, MPI_ERR_OTHER, "**fail");
        MPIU_ERR_ADD(mpi_errno_ret, mpi_errno);
    }
}
else {
    /* use a binomial tree algorithm */ 
    mpi_errno = MPIR_Reduce_binomial(sendbuf, recvbuf, count, datatype, op, root, comm_ptr, errflag);
    if (mpi_errno) {
        /* for communication errors, just record the error but continue */
        *errflag = TRUE;
        MPIU_ERR_SET(mpi_errno, MPI_ERR_OTHER, "**fail");
        MPIU_ERR_ADD(mpi_errno_ret, mpi_errno);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Hristo said about debugging in MPICH (it's not named MPICH2 anymore), you can do some very manual tracing if you really want to using the MPICH debugging logs. I wouldn't recommend it as it can be probably way more verbose than you need, but if you really need to know how the collective operations work on the backend, you can check out the [wiki page](http://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Debug_Event_Logging) on debugging to figure out what you need.